# how to use llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions> - Linking error

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

I am trying to use llvm::cl to parse command line arguments. As the start, I am trying to write a simple driver that parses an input file from the command line via llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions.

```
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    llvm::cl::ParseCommandLineOptions(argc, argv, "quad2bitcode generator\n");
    llvm::cl::opt<std::string> InputFilename(llvm::cl::Positional,
                                             llvm::cl::desc("<input file>"),
                                             llvm::cl::Required);
    ...
```

When compiling, I am getting the following linking error. Any help will be appreciated!

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZTIN4llvm2cl18GenericOptionValueE", referenced from:
      __ZTIN4llvm2cl15OptionValueCopyINSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEEE in quadreader.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Are you linking with `libLLVMCore` or `libLLVMSupport` ?

Comment: I listed both in CMakeLists.txt - llvm_map_components_to_libnames(llvm_libs support core irreader native)